# HTML form accessibility: tab key focus skips newly shown field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a form that contains a select field that is only shown when the value of the previous select field is set to a specific value. Here is a simplified version where a hidden "states" select field appears if "USA" is selected as the country:

HTML:

```
<style>
  label {
    display:inline-block;    
    min-width:100px;        
    padding:3px;
  }
  .hidden{
    display:none;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <label for="country">Country</label>
  <select id="country">
    <option>Czech Republic</option>
    <option>USA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="stateContainer"  class="hidden">
  <label for="state">State</label>
  <select id="state">
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Arizona</option>
    <option>Arkansas</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $("#country").on("change",function(){
    if ( $(this).val() === "USA") {
      $("#stateContainer").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      $("#stateContainer").addClass("hidden");
    }
  })
})
```

...and here it is in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xoundboy/a2HdZ/5/

it works fine when using a mouse but if the user is restricted to keyboard input only then UX is broken. You can see this if focus is in the country field and you use the up/down arrows to select "USA" as the country and then the tab key to move to the next field. Instead of moving to the newly shown "state" field, it skips over to the "name" field.

I could probably fix it by capturing the tab key press in JS, forcing the focus onto the newly shown field and preventing default behaviour but that seems like an ugly hack. What is the best practice for handling what must be quite a common scenario?

Comment: can you please check which solution is acceptable to you. I really do not like my answer to be down-voted if it works.

Comment: I agree - quite rude to downvote a working solution without any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is not triggered when up/down key is pressed. So the `change` event can be triggered on a key press.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2HdZ/14/) example for the code changes. Hope it helps.

**EDIT 1**
I checked with different browsers and found out that this problem is in firefox and hence the solution is for firefox. For chrome the fiddle in question works perfectly fine for me.

**EDIT 2**
My previous fiddle had `change` triggered on `keypress`. It seems firefox changed somethings and it no more works. I have updated the event to `keyup`.

Comment: the change event is triggered when using up and down keys on a select field.

Comment: @Patrick Evans, it appears that Puneet is correct, pls remove the downvote (if it was you who gave it) as this is the correct answer. When I asked the question I'd only been testing it in FF and not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

just use the tabindex element property, tab order goes from lowest to highest value

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2HdZ/7/)

```
<div>
  <label for="country">Country</label>
  <select id="country" tabindex=1>
    <option>Czech Republic</option>
    <option>USA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="stateContainer"  class="hidden">
  <label for="state">State</label>
  <select id="state" tabindex=2>
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Arizona</option>
    <option>Arkansas</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" tabindex=3 />
</div>
```

Comment: The tabindex works only when the div is visible. Hence this will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Puneet, it works perfectly, check the fiddle. His problem is once the previously hidden field is shown it doesnt get the focus when tabbing.

Comment: It is not working for me. I am using firefox 22.0. And I gave the solution wrt my browser. I do not think my answer was to be down-voted for that.